# Rstudio and R in command window in anaconda have different enviroments

Tags: r, anaconda

I have a confusion when using R inAanaconda. I created an environment called "rstudio_env" and installed Rstudio in this environment. So far so good.

When I use Rstudio, I just open it without activating the "rstudio_env" and I also installed a lot of packages here. After updating the R through Rstudio, my new home path in Rstudio changes to some local default path. For example, the original **.libPaths() = "C:/Users/someuser/.conda/envs/rstudio/lib/R/library"** and new **.libPaths()= "C:/someuser/Document/R/R-4.0.2/library"**.

Now when I use Rstudio, I have the new path. When I use R in the "rstudio_env" in conda, I still have the old path. This really confuses me, because I want to have the same libraries for both approaches. Why the updating changes the path of RStudio rather than only updating the contents?

I am too lazy to activate the "rstudio_env" when using Rstudio. That might be the reason for the conflict. But for now, how can I make the libraries consistent? I know I can change **.libPaths** manually, but are there other ways, some clearer ways?

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled everything and made everything clean